# Problems with Linq(join)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I am writting a query with linq(follow code bellow). I am looking for data from db.imovel and for each one bring a picture nested into db.fotoimovel. Keep in mind that I may have more than one picture for each db.imovel data.

The issue is when I run, it returns me all the pictures with the same db.imovel data in all of them.

It works for me if return the db.imovel data with just one(may be the first picture) from db.fotoimovel.

Code:

```
var retorno = (from c in db.fotoimovel
                    join p in db.imovel on c.idImovel equals p.idImovel
                    where p.MetragemImovel >= metragem1 && p.MetragemImovel <= metragem2 &&
                    p.StatusImovel == opcao && 
                    ((String.IsNullOrEmpty(bairro)) || p.BairroImovel == bairro) &&
                    ((imovel == null) || (p.TipoImovel == imovel)) &&
                    ((carros == null) || (p.QtdVagaGaragemImovel == carros)) &&
                    ((quartos == null) || (p.QtdQuartoImovel == quartos))
                    select new DadosImovel
                    {
                        Id = p.idImovel,
                        Titulo = p.TituloImovel,
                        Descricao = p.DescricaoImovel,
                        Foto = c.NomeFotoImovel,
                        TipoImovel = p.TipoImovel,
                        Endereco = p.EnderecoImovel,
                        Complemento = p.ComplementoImovel,
                        Bairro = p.BairroImovel,
                        Cidade = p.CidadeImovel,
                        Estado = p.EstadoImovel,
                        CEP = p.CEPImovel,
                        MetragemImovel = p.MetragemImovel,
                        QtdComodoImovel = p.QtdComodoImovel,
                        QtdQuartoImovel = p.QtdQuartoImovel,
                        QtdBanheiroImovel = p.QtdBanheiroImovel,
                        QtdVagaGaragemImovel = p.QtdVagaGaragemImovel,
                        QtdAndarImovel = p.QtdAndarImovel,
                        Status = p.StatusImovel,
                        Ativo = p.AtivoImovel
                    }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to do a join if the relationship between the tables is encoded into your model--unless, of course, the database doesn't have foreign key relationships or something.

Comment: btw, it might be helpful if you gave the ORM utilized..  Linq to SQL? Linq to Entity Framework? Linq to some other ORM?